# agGrid : custom header column binding not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ag-grid

I'm currently trying to add an angular directive in agGrid header. For that i passed a function in headerCellRenderer as following :

My gridOptions :

```
this.columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Height", field: "rowHeight"},
    {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 180},
    {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90},
    {headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120},
    {headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90}
];
this.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    //enableSorting: true,
    headerHeight: 60,
    //enableFilter: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    angularCompileRows:true,
    angularCompileHeaders: true,
    headerCellRenderer: (params) => 
        {return   this.headerCellRendererFunc(params);},
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
};
```

My function is defined as followed :

```
headerCellRendererFunc(params) {
    const headerColDef = params.colDef;
    headerColDef.name =  headerColDef.headerName;
    headerColDef.isMetadata = false;
    return '<header column="headerColDef"></header>';
}
```

As a result my directive is rendered but the "column" binding is empty, i don't understand how i have to pass the object to my directive.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: strangely when i pass a dummy value like : '<datagrid-header column="'+ca+'"></datagrid-header>'; with "ca" being a number, this number effectively goes to my directive ...

Answer (score 2):

If this can help anyone, i've just understood my mistake : the params arguments has a scope and that's the one being passed to the directive, so all i had to do was passing my object in the scope to have it work !

```
 params.$scope.column = headerColDef;
```

with the html looking like this :

```
return '<header column="column"></header>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ag-grid gridOptions properties `angularCompileHeaders: true`(Default is false)

Try it! It's work for me.

Ref:https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/index.php